# How to integrate Android GUI with Unity 3d

Tags: android, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create an AR messaging application for Android using Unity 3d, however I'm not finding much help with developing a decent GUI on Unity. How would I go about developing the GUI in Java and then integrating it with Unity?

Answer (score -2):

I recommend you to use unity´s OnGui method to do the interface.

You can check the documentation here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/gui-Basics.html

Here you have a nice tutorial I´ve just found

http://3dgep.com/gui-scripting-in-unity/

Hope this help you, good luck!